# Hyperledger Fabric peer channel fetch config problem

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to add a new organization to Fabric's v2.2 test-network.
When I execute the command (on configUpdate.sh; env vars are correctly setup):

```
  peer channel fetch config config_block.pb -o orderer.example.com:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com -c $CHANNEL --tls --cafile "$ORDERER_CA"
```

I obtain:

```
Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp: lookup orderer.example.com on 193.231.252.1:53: no such host"
```

Why does not the orderer client dial to localhost:7050 (orderer's address)? EDIT: 193.231.252.1 is the nameserver configured at /etc/resolv.conf and it is reachable (via ping) [Full log is here.](https://gist.github.com/RafaelAPB/75e73ef53529694a0156cee34207ced8)

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2  e6944b966388
```

Orderer logs:

[...]

```
2021-05-23 13:11:22.188 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 1874 Error reading from 172.19.0.1:40024: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2021-05-23 13:11:22.188 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 1875 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.1:40024 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=5.499193ms
2021-05-23 13:11:23.038 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] propose -> INFO 1876 Created block [1021], there are 0 blocks in flight channel=mychannel node=1
2021-05-23 13:11:23.049 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] writeBlock -> INFO 1877 Writing block [1021] (Raft index: 1023) to ledger channel=mychannel node=1
2021-05-23 13:11:23.362 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 1878 Error reading from 172.19.0.1:40044: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2021-05-23 13:11:23.362 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 1879 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.1:40044 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=5.423335ms
/ #
```

Peers from org1 and org2 can connect to the orderer.

Anybody has any advice? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Port 53 is used for DNS requests, so this address:port `193.231.252.1:53` is being used for a DNS lookup trying to resolve orderer.example.com which I'm guessing it cannot do

Comment: Thanks, @david_k, that is insightful. However, why would peer channel fetch config try to resolve orderer.example.com via that port?

Comment: all hostsnames have to be resolved to an ip address so the command is sending a request to 193.231.252.1 to try to resolve orderer.example.com to an ip address

Comment: that is correct , @david_k, that ip is on of the nameservers configured for that docker container. any idea why can't orderer.example.com be resolved to an IP address? I think that, in principle, it should be resolved to 127.0.0.1:7050 or 127.0.0.1:7053

Comment: Is that docker container on the same network as orderer.example.com docker container ?

Comment: Yes - https://gist.github.com/RafaelAPB/824d0f6e7687e0dff23878cdb848b708.
EDIT: that docker container runs a series of docker containers implementing the test-network. So in practice what is calling orderer.example.com is the client (on behalf of org1, as per default, I believe).

Comment: you can check by using `docker inspect orderer.example.com` to see what network it is on and then do the same for the docker container you are trying to run the command in

Comment: I also see you think it should resolve to 127.0.0.1 (localhost), that will only happen of you run the command inside the orderer.example.com container itself (ignoring the ability to bind containers to the host network which I assume you aren't doing)

Comment: Actually I don't have great evidence... The network of the orderer is cactusfabrictestnetwork_test, but I can't find any reference in the parent container.

The Fabric all in one container (docker container that runs the other containers) has this config: https://gist.github.com/RafaelAPB/24774a453edf01077e72170e8a4cafc3

The orderer: https://gist.github.com/RafaelAPB/19bd0b130eef955fa312358a3fa05b35

I tend to think they are in the same network, because the channel boostrap is successful, and issuing transactions against that network using orgs 1 or 2 are also possible

Comment: well, one is on the bridge network and the other is on it's own specified network, so I would guess that you have docker networking issues with what you are trying to achieve. I'm not an expert on all the various docker networking capabilities but hat's my best guess as to the problem you are experiencing

Comment: Appreciate your help, @david_k. It looks like the problem was that orderer.example.com was not resolvable, so replacing that with localhost and the corresponding port worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`peer channel fetch config config_block.pb -o IPAddress:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com -c $CHANNEL --tls --cafile "$ORDERER_CA"`

Make sure your port is an accessible or open port.

Answer (score 0):

edit your `/etc/hosts` like these,add the following content:

```
127.0.0.1 orderer.example.com

#or
#your IP orderer.example.com
```

these will tell your client how to find yor orderer server

Comment: This is also a valid answer!